# How can I make my top bar elements clickable in responsive?

Tags: css, image, menu, header, position

I have a slick-menu, a logo, and a search element in my top bar. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to make them all clickable at the same time within both my tablet and mobile responsive. Because of a z-index, I think they are stacked/transparent--which is the issue. I can only either make the menu + search clickable or the logo. I've tried changing them to inline-block on each element, tried the pointer-events property, and also changing around the z-index values, but nothing has been successful. How do I fix this?

You can view my website here: [www.rachelclayton.co](https://www.rachelclayton.co)

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #top-bar-logo {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 941px) {

#top-bar-logo {
    display: block;
}   
#top-bar-logo img {
    max-width:60%;
    height:auto;
}
#mobile-social {
    display: none;
}
    #top-bar {
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    line-height:40px;
    background:#ffff;
    z-index:99999;
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
#header {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#top-bar {
    height:35px;
    position:relative;
    line-height:35px;
    background:#ffff;
    z-index:99999;
}
#top-bar-logo img {
    max-width:70%;
    height:auto;
}
#top-bar-logo {
    display: inline-block;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding this post.

Specifically what does this mean "When I shift it up to the top bar, it becomes un-clickable."? What is "it" as in "shift it up"?

I see in your site you wrapped the `<img>` with `<a>` - that is good.

```
  <a href="https://rachelclayton.co/"><img src="https://rachelclayton.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/RClogo.png" alt="Rachel Clayton" /></a>
```

Have you tried wrapping the  `<div id="top-bar-logo">` in the `<a>` tag as well?

Comment: Sorry--I meant the the "it" as the image/logo. I've continued to fiddle around, and think the issue was that the z-index of the logo was less than that of the slick-navigation-menu (the 3 bars on the left side of the mobile top bar). I tried putting a higher z-index value on the logo. Now the logo is clickable in the top-bar, but the slick-menu becomes non-clickable (because it's lower z-index value). I'm guessing it has something to do with the widths of the top-bar elements. I'm thinking display: inline-block on each element and complimentary widths or a flex-box. Any thoughts?

Comment: I could possibly use a "pointer-event" but I don't know how to make the logo, menu, and search still clickable with it.